# Can I limit how much graphics memory Ubuntu uses? (Cuda/OpenCL related)

Tags: programming, memory, opencl, cuda

I have a test suite that uses openCL and I notice that I pass more if I close down everything and just run the tests. I fail more if I have lots of programs open on my desktop. Is it possible to cap how much vram my displays are sucking up?

Comment: Is compositing on? Do you have fancy shadows, translucency, etc? Try turning compositing off.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using a compositing window manager. They use the GPU for their special effects, which means that in addition to the framebuffer in VRAM, every window is backed by a texture in VRAM and shaders are used to render the desktop. If you use a simpler window manager with no fancy or 3d effects there should be less contention for your GPU resources.

(Some compositing window managers can be run with compositing features disabled, so try that before you go shopping for an entirely new window manager.)